# IF statement not working with two variables, echo and grep

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

I have below code that is not working and I don't know why:

```
$ cat test.sh
#Variables
list_of_items=$(ls /items)
my_item=ccc

#Check if my item is on the list
if [ echo ${list_of_items} | grep -wc ${my_item} -eq 0 ]
 then echo "This item is not on the list."
fi

$ ./test.sh
./test.sh: line 6: [: missing `]'
grep: ccc: No such file or directory
grep: 0: No such file or directory
grep: ]: No such file or directory
$
```

The idea is to check if one exact word exists in a list (ls) of words. Can you help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Daniel

Comment: Do you really want to test if a word exists in a list of words, or if a **file** `${my_item}` exists in a **directory** `${items}`? if the latter, then you can use `if [ -e "${items}/${my_item}" ]; then` - no need for `ls` or `grep`

Comment: @steeldriver given that the OP used `grep -w` I think this is a good assumption. Want to make it an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close!

```
$ cat test.sh
#Variables
list_of_items=$(ls /items)
my_item=ccc

#Check if my item is on the list
if [ $( echo ${list_of_items} | grep -wc ${my_item} ) -eq 0 ]
 then echo "This item is not on the list."
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

bash:

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob
matches=( /items/*"$my_item"* )
if (( "${#matches[@]}" == 0 )); then
  echo "File matching $my_item not found"
fi
```

Comment: can you explain when and why we make use of `shopt -s nullglob`

Comment: @codeholic24 Without `nullglob`, there'll always be at least one item in the array, because the default is to leave inmatched glob expressions in their unexpanded form. That is, it'll just create an array with a single element, "/items/*ccc*". BTW, I recommend turning it off afterward with `shopt -u nullglob`, to avoid weird effects on later commands.